# If $Y=X_1 +X_2 +X_3$ where each $X_i$ are independent and normally distributed...

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

**The Problem:**
Given three means and three standard deviations of three normally distributed random variables representing the amount of time it takes to complete each of three steps of a job, what is the probability that the total time the job takes is less than 40 minutes. Essentially what is $P(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 <40)$?

**My Work:**
I started to work out the pdf of $Y$ by means of transforming the CDF with two more dummy random variables $Y_2=X_2$ and $Y_3=X_3$, and somewhere in the midst of computing the Jacobian, I thought "There must be an easier way." I couldn't figure out the bounds of integration for using the CDF method of transformation, So I looked up the solution and saw that the author added the parameters of each $X_i$ and claimed that their sum are the parameters of $Y$, which also had a normal distribution, which leads to...

**The Question:**
If $Y=X_1 +X_2 +X_3$ where each $X_i$ is independent and normally distributed, Is the distribution of $Y$ also a normal distribution, with parameters being the sums of each of the $X$ variables? How is this justified?

Comment: The mean of the sum is the sum of the means, and the same with variance (which means that standard deviations sum in a Pythagorean-theorem-like style). That's true for any finite set of independent variables, regardless of distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $Y$ is also normally distributed. We have that
$$
Y\sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+\sigma_3^2).
$$
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) for more details and proofs.

Comment: Thanks, the proofs on Wikipedia were great. Sometimes they are hard to understand, but this cleared up my confusion perfectly.